# Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[pgdg-centos93]'

Tags: postgresql, chef-infra, chef-recipe

## Environment

- Chef
- CentOS
- PostGres
- Rails

**Amazon cloud server**

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-0-250 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 28 21:11:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Put an Amazon CentOS instance to sleep for a couple of months and started it again today. To bring everything up-to-date, the "magic" should happen (*figure of speech*) with `sudo chef-client`, at least that was what was expected. And to my current experience for this particular , **Chef** has brought to my project almost more overhead than gain in time. (NOTE: This is a side comment related to a personal experience.)

Here is my latest headache

```
Recipe: postgresql::yum_pgdg_postgresql
  * remote_file[/var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm] action create (up to date)
  * package[pgdg-centos93] action install
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[pgdg-centos93]'
================================================================================


Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm returned 2, expected 0


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/yum_pgdg_postgresql.rb

 43: package repo_rpm_package do
 44:   provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rpm
 45:   source "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/#{repo_rpm_filename}"
 46:   action :install
 47: end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/yum_pgdg_postgresql.rb:43:in `from_file'

package("pgdg-centos93") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rpm
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  package_name "pgdg-centos93"
  source "/var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm"
  version "9.3-1"
  cookbook_name "postgresql"
  recipe_name "yum_pgdg_postgresql"
end




Running handlers:
[2016-02-02T12:34:02+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete

[2016-02-02T12:34:02+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2016-02-02T12:34:02+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 8 resources updated in 42.119165396 seconds
[2016-02-02T12:34:03+00:00] ERROR: package[pgdg-centos93] (postgresql::yum_pgdg_postgresql line 43) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm returned 2, expected 0
[2016-02-02T12:34:03+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Any pointers are most desperately welcomed. I just don't manage to understand the ERROR

## UPDATE

As suggested

```
$ sudo rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm
[sudo] password for ed: 
    package pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch (which is newer than pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch) is already installed
```

Running Chef in debug mode

```
  * package[pgdg-centos93] action install[2016-02-02T14:05:16+00:00] INFO: Processing package[pgdg-centos93] action install (postgresql::yum_pgdg_postgresql line 43)
[2016-02-02T14:05:16+00:00] DEBUG: package[pgdg-centos93] checking rpm status
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: package[pgdg-centos93] checking install state
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: package[pgdg-centos93] current version is 9.3-2
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: Executing rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: ---- Begin output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: STDOUT: 
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: STDERR:  package pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch (which is newer than pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch) is already installed
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: ---- End output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: Ran rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm returned 2

================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[pgdg-centos93]'
================================================================================


Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm returned 2, expected 0
---- Begin output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----
STDOUT: STDERR:     package pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch (which is newer than pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch) is already installed
---- End output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----



Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/yum_pgdg_postgresql.rb

 43: package repo_rpm_package do
 44:   provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rpm
 45:   source "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/#{repo_rpm_filename}"
 46:   action :install
 47: end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/yum_pgdg_postgresql.rb:43:in `from_file'

package("pgdg-centos93") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rpm
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  package_name "pgdg-centos93"
  source "/var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm"
  version "9.3-1"
  cookbook_name "postgresql"
  recipe_name "yum_pgdg_postgresql"
end



[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: Re-raising exception: Chef::Exceptions::Exec - package[pgdg-centos93] (postgresql::yum_pgdg_postgresql line 43) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm returned 2, expected 0
---- Begin output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----
STDOUT: STDERR:     package pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch (which is newer than pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch) is already installed
---- End output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----

/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:158:in `handle_command_failures'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:104:in `run_command_and_return_stdout_stderr'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:79:in `run_command'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:171:in `run_command_with_systems_locale'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider/package/rpm.rb:98:in `install_package'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:82:in `block in action_install'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider.rb:155:in `converge_by'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:80:in `action_install'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider.rb:120:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource.rb:637:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:98:in `block in execute_each_resource'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:96:in `execute_each_resource'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:345:in `converge'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:431:in `do_run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:213:in `block in run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `fork'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application.rb:217:in `run_chef_client'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:328:in `block in run_application'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:317:in `loop'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:317:in `run_application'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application.rb:67:in `run'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
  /usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'

Running handlers:
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete

[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: package[pgdg-centos93] (postgresql::yum_pgdg_postgresql line 43) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm returned 2, expected 0
---- Begin output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----
STDOUT: STDERR:     package pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch (which is newer than pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch) is already installed
---- End output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----

/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:158:in `handle_command_failures'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:104:in `run_command_and_return_stdout_stderr'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:79:in `run_command'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:171:in `run_command_with_systems_locale'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider/package/rpm.rb:98:in `install_package'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:82:in `block in action_install'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider.rb:155:in `converge_by'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:80:in `action_install'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider.rb:120:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource.rb:637:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:98:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:96:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:345:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:431:in `do_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:213:in `block in run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application.rb:217:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:328:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:317:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:317:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application.rb:67:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'
Chef Client failed. 8 resources updated in 42.825243439 seconds
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] INFO: Sending resource update report (run-id: ac041d25-eba7-4865-a20a-d16ffa60acef)
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: {"action"=>"end", "resources"=>[{"type"=>"ruby_block", "name"=>"run-iptables-resources-early", "id"=>"run-iptables-resources-early", "after"=>{}, "before"=>{}, "duration"=>"16183", "delta"=>"", "result"=>"run", "cookbook_name"=>"simple_iptables", "cookbook_version"=>"0.6.0"}, {"type"=>"package", "name"=>"pgdg-centos93", "id"=>"pgdg-centos93", "after"=>{:version=>"9.3-1", :options=>nil}, "before"=>{:version=>"9.3-2", :options=>nil}, "duration"=>"961", "delta"=>"", "result"=>"install", "cookbook_name"=>"postgresql", "cookbook_version"=>"3.4.0"}], "status"=>"failure", "run_list"=>"[\"role[website]\"]", "total_res_count"=>"27", "data"=>{"exception"=>{"class"=>"#<Chef::Exceptions::Exec: package[pgdg-centos93] (postgresql::yum_pgdg_postgresql line 43) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm returned 2, expected 0\n---- Begin output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----\nSTDOUT: STDERR: \tpackage pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch (which is newer than pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch) is already installed\n---- End output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----\n>", "message"=>"package[pgdg-centos93] (postgresql::yum_pgdg_postgresql line 43) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm returned 2, expected 0\n---- Begin output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----\nSTDOUT: STDERR: \tpackage pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch (which is newer than pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch) is already installed\n---- End output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----\n", "backtrace"=>"[\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:158:in `handle_command_failures'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:104:in `run_command_and_return_stdout_stderr'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:79:in `run_command'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/command.rb:171:in `run_command_with_systems_locale'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider/package/rpm.rb:98:in `install_package'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:82:in `block in action_install'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider.rb:155:in `converge_by'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider/package.rb:80:in `action_install'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/provider.rb:120:in `run_action'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource.rb:637:in `run_action'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:98:in `block in execute_each_resource'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:96:in `execute_each_resource'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:345:in `converge'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:431:in `do_run'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:213:in `block in run'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `fork'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `run'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application.rb:217:in `run_chef_client'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:328:in `block in run_application'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:317:in `loop'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:317:in `run_application'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/lib/chef/application.rb:67:in `run'\",\"/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.12.4/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'\",\"/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'\",\"/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `<main>'\"]", "description"=>{"title"=>"Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[pgdg-centos93]'", "sections"=>[{"Chef::Exceptions::Exec"=>"rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm returned 2, expected 0\n---- Begin output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----\nSTDOUT: STDERR: \tpackage pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch (which is newer than pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch) is already installed\n---- End output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----\n"}, {"Resource Declaration:"=>"# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/yum_pgdg_postgresql.rb\n\n 43: package repo_rpm_package do\n 44:   provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rpm\n 45:   source \"\#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/\#{repo_rpm_filename}\"\n 46:   action :install\n 47: end\n"}, {"Compiled Resource:"=>"# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/postgresql/recipes/yum_pgdg_postgresql.rb:43:in `from_file'\n\npackage(\"pgdg-centos93\") do\n  provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rpm\n  action [:install]\n  retries 0\n  retry_delay 2\n  guard_interpreter :default\n  package_name \"pgdg-centos93\"\n  source \"/var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm\"\n  version \"9.3-1\"\n  cookbook_name \"postgresql\"\n  recipe_name \"yum_pgdg_postgresql\"\nend\n"}]}}}, "start_time"=>"2016-02-02 14:04:41 +0000", "end_time"=>"2016-02-02 14:05:17 +0000"}
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: Sending compressed run data...
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: Signing the request as ec2-production-web
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: String to sign: 'Method:POST
Hashed Path:ZNfsXWm0ScG9Y7tct4xU2t8Ruc4=
X-Ops-Content-Hash:JebmaJ0FR9SKdg1Whn6EXf9AjeY=
X-Ops-Timestamp:2016-02-02T14:05:17Z
X-Ops-UserId:ec2-production-web'
Header hash: {"X-Ops-Sign"=>"algorithm=sha1;version=1.0;", "X-Ops-Userid"=>"ec2-production-web", "X-Ops-Timestamp"=>"2016-02-02T14:05:17Z", "X-Ops-Content-Hash"=>"JebmaJ0FR9SKdg1Whn6EXf9AjeY=", "X-Ops-Authorization-1"=>"i25tlVgWl76JsqbNZFU9HKNBWbeIUUdOOIkInmsgw4cPI8zctpzNRZi9e5JF", "X-Ops-Authorization-2"=>"flygf7pnwtIH0UFpUJSukmHAklqGL2pQlMy3oRoSxQhzvYTW+njD4SznjEY/", "X-Ops-Authorization-3"=>"Cf0nkNUkf0mlch5oTiU9PD6md/irpT0IIv+fYCBS1HRoYpbiJVWuYqHchgOo", "X-Ops-Authorization-4"=>"Ir0DnFtZ4SFucPATkHWQMxx/c1tAY1sSoQZv02kceDJVPuMAarRI8gKzOQ6+", "X-Ops-Authorization-5"=>"Z6TBmJWXVqdRU4CAvjihr87hVadAYQQZURuQCEwsnxFUnxDZkrz1jDV+PnhQ", "X-Ops-Authorization-6"=>"uXPPOgdI5DuF45RvJfoFO8AvTkg+QCEwkqwCAY+e3w=="}
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: Initiating POST to https://api.opscode.com/organizations/[filtered]/reports/nodes/ec2-production-web/runs/ac041d25-eba7-4865-a20a-d16ffa60acef
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: ---- HTTP Request Header Data: ----
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: X-Ops-Reporting-Protocol-Version: 0.1.0
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: Content-Encoding: gzip
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-SIGN: algorithm=sha1;version=1.0;
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-USERID: ec2-production-web
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-TIMESTAMP: 2016-02-02T14:05:17Z
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-CONTENT-HASH: JebmaJ0FR9SKdg1Whn6EXf9AjeY=
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-1: i25tlVgWl76JsqbNZFU9HKNBWbeIUUdOOIkInmsgw4cPI8zctpzNRZi9e5JF
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-2: flygf7pnwtIH0UFpUJSukmHAklqGL2pQlMy3oRoSxQhzvYTW+njD4SznjEY/
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-3: Cf0nkNUkf0mlch5oTiU9PD6md/irpT0IIv+fYCBS1HRoYpbiJVWuYqHchgOo
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-4: Ir0DnFtZ4SFucPATkHWQMxx/c1tAY1sSoQZv02kceDJVPuMAarRI8gKzOQ6+
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-5: Z6TBmJWXVqdRU4CAvjihr87hVadAYQQZURuQCEwsnxFUnxDZkrz1jDV+PnhQ
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: X-OPS-AUTHORIZATION-6: uXPPOgdI5DuF45RvJfoFO8AvTkg+QCEwkqwCAY+e3w==
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: HOST: api.opscode.com:443
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: X-REMOTE-REQUEST-ID: ac041d25-eba7-4865-a20a-d16ffa60acef
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: Content-Length: 1391
[2016-02-02T14:05:17+00:00] DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Request Header Data ----
[2016-02-02T14:05:18+00:00] DEBUG: ---- HTTP Status and Header Data: ----
[2016-02-02T14:05:18+00:00] DEBUG: HTTP 1.1 200 OK
[2016-02-02T14:05:18+00:00] DEBUG: content-type: application/json
[2016-02-02T14:05:18+00:00] DEBUG: date: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 14:05:18 GMT
[2016-02-02T14:05:18+00:00] DEBUG: server: openresty/1.9.3.1
[2016-02-02T14:05:18+00:00] DEBUG: content-length: 2
[2016-02-02T14:05:18+00:00] DEBUG: connection: Close
[2016-02-02T14:05:18+00:00] DEBUG: ---- End HTTP Status/Header Data ----
[2016-02-02T14:05:18+00:00] ERROR: package[pgdg-centos93] (postgresql::yum_pgdg_postgresql line 43) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm returned 2, expected 0
---- Begin output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----
STDOUT: STDERR:     package pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch (which is newer than pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch) is already installed
---- End output of rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm ----

[2016-02-02T14:05:18+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
[ed@ip-10-0-0-250 ~]$
```

## UPDATE 2

Removed package `pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch` which was newer than the one Chef was trying to install

```
yum remove pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch
```

then ran `sudo chef-client -l debug` again.

Ran into another blocking issue that once resolved takes me to the first problem I had. So I am going in circles. Will validate the one helpful answer because, I believe that there is no easy solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that the command `rpm  -U /var/chef/cache/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm` has an exit code of 2, which indicates there was an error. Either run that command by hand to see the error details or run `chef-client -l debug` to enable Chef's debug-level output which will include the stdout and stderr from the subprocess.

So your broader question: Chef is not magic nor is it a Platform-as-a-Service on its own. Chef itself offers fairly basic primitives like package installs and templated config files, and in general those just do what they say on the tin. When you start either building your own complex cookbooks or using the community cookbooks you can get much more turn-key magic like "add this to your run list and out pops a PostgreSQL server" but with that complexity comes a lot more bugs. Community cookbooks especially are of widely varying quality and you should always check if something is from an author you personally or institutionally trust and if not probably read all the code in it and make sure you like it. Same basic process as with any software development environment when you start consuming external tools/libraries/gems/packages/etc.

Comment: Cheers mate! I do sense the value of Chef, and proposed it in a couple of projects, yet I had to also point out my negatives. They are rather objective and possibly not very useful to the issue itself. Nevermind. Thanks for reminding me of the `-l debug`, I remember using that to resolve other issues long time ago. I have Updated my question with the `debug` info while I track the problem down to its source. Thx!

Comment: @joël Seems so, the message is pretty clear. Don't yell at the tools when it's a problem of system management as a root cause...

Comment: @coderanger I removed the package with newer version `yum remove pgdg-centos93-9.3-2.noarch` than the one Chef was trying to install `9.3-1` and that resolved. It was easy to fix but overwhelming as I had not touched Chef in months. Thanks for the pointer and I apologize for the side distracting comment. Didn't mean to undermine the tool. I know why I have adopted it, I confess however a moment of doubt on whether it was a good choice for my project considering some of the issues BUT I am happy again, thanks to your little push! Cheers